# Is it possible to have a custom email address for a Google Group?

Tags: google-groups

We have setup a Google Group which we are using as so we can share Google Documents with group and all the members are automatically added in.

Currently our Google Groups email is like this `example@googlegroups.com`. Is it possible to brand this with a custom domain / custom email address?

So it would be `example@mydomain.com`?

We are not on a G Suite paid plan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, I'm afraid not. You'll need a G Suite paid plan to do that.

I suppose you *could* set up an autoforward mailbox from your domain that would automatically send all messages on to the Google Groups address, but messages would still come *from* the Google Group, munging anyone's reply.

Comment: Thanks @ale do you know if i have a G suite paid plan can i create a google group with a custom email address, but in the google group place memebers that are outside of my G suite plan (they would be either free users eg. gmail or users who have a customdomain for their free google account, or users from a another G suite paid plan which is not managed by me)

Comment: Yes - your paid G Suite subscription would only need to have one user, you.   For the group, you'd simply have to check a box to allow people external to your domain to join (with or without a Google account).

Answer (score 0):

... or you could install a self-hosted mailing list solution, like [GNU Mailman](https://www.list.org/) or [Sympa](https://www.sympa.org/). But that sounds like more trouble than you are looking for.